# Using switchcase to check if userinput is a string or int or a float

Tags: java, switch-statement

Basically I would like to build a switchcase statement if check if a user input is a integer , float or a String. I would like to use methods such as hasCheckInt() , hasCheckDouble() to check the respective datatype.

Some of the code is missing yes because I do not know what to put in. 
Forgive the java noob.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class helloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
      switch()) {
      case 1: 

      if(userInput.hasNextInt()) {
      System.out.println("Int");
      }
      break;



     case 2: 
     if(userInput.hasNextLine()) {
     System.out.println("String");
     }
     break;
     }
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically I would like to build a switchcase statement if check if a user input is a integer , float or a String. I would like to use methods such as hasCheckInt() , hasCheckDouble() to check the respective datatype.

You can't, the `case`s of a `switch` must be constants, not the results of an expression (including a function call).

Instead, you'll need `if/else if/else`

```
if (hasCheckInt(argumentHere)) {
    // `hasCheckInt` returned `true`
    // ...
}
else if (hasCheckDouble(argumentHere)) {
    // `hasCheckDouble` returned `true`
    // ...
}
else {
    // None of the above matched
}
```

Comment: I do how to do it using if statements. It's just that I would like to do it using switch. Is is not possible?

Comment: Correct, it is not possible. In Java, the `case` of a `switch` has to be a constant: `case 42:` It **can't** be an expression: `case hasCheckInt(args):`. (This is true of **most**, but not all, languages that have `switch`. JavaScript is the only exception I know of, but I'm sure there are others.)